# How to copy one user's directory and overwrite onto anther users directory

Tags: linux, mv

Env : Centos7

---

User A's directory : `/home/A/dir`
User B's directory : `/home/B/dir`

---

`/home/A/dir`'s  content(sub directories) :

```
a b c
```

`/home/B/dir`'s  content(sub directories) :

```
a b c d e f
```

---

My goal and conditions :

- I want to overwrite A's every sub-directories onto B's directory.
- I will never know which directories will be copied. (cannot specify directories)
- B has some directories that must not be deleted. (cannot `rm -rf /home/B/dir`)

---

My failed attempts

1.

```
[B@server]$ sudo cp -pr /home/A/dir/* /home/B/dir
cp: cannot stat ‘/home/A/dir/*’: No such file or directory
```

2. 

```
[A@server]$ sudo cp -pr /home/A/dir/* /tmp/A/

[B@server]$ sudo mv /tmp/A/* /home/B/dir/
mv: cannot move ‘/tmp/A/a’ to ‘/home/B/dir/a’: Directory not empty
mv: cannot move ‘/tmp/A/b’ to ‘/home/B/dir/b’: Directory not empty
mv: cannot move ‘/tmp/A/c’ to ‘/home/B/dir/c’: Directory not empty
```

*EDIT
I'm currently using a workaround

```
[A@server]$ sudo cp -pr /home/A/dir/* /tmp/A/
[B@server]$ sudo cp -pr /tmp/A/* /home/B/dir
[B@server]$ sudo rm -rf /tmp/A/*
```

but with this command, when a file is deleted from A, B can still have that removed file.

Comment: What happens if you ran the 2nd item in the last batch of commands as `sudo mv -f /tmp/A/* /home/B/dir/`?

Comment: @Giacomo1968 it still says `Directory not empty`

Comment: Use rsync -a. mv and cp will refuse this by design